# relation does not exist ActiveSupport::Concern

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, activesupport, activesupport-concern

I have simple module and it included to my model

```
module Inputable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    has_many :inputs, as: :inputable, dependent: :destroy
  end
end

 class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    include Inputable
end
```

But when i try to call `Product.first.inputs` i have got an error

```
    PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "inputs" does not exist
LINE 5: WHERE a.attrelid = '"inputs"'::regclass                                     
: SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod)

Product.reflect_on_all_associations.map { |assoc| assoc.name}
=>[:inputs]
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Did you generate the Input model and run `rake db:migrate`? Silly question, but thought I'd ask.

Comment: ye you right, i didn't

Comment: Can you show us the code of your Input migration and the input model?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've generated the `Input` model and run the migrations.

Also, when I use the `included` hook, it tends to look more like this:

```
module Inputable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  self.included(base)
    base.class_eval do 
      has_many :inputs, as: :inputable, dependent: :destroy
    end
  end

end
```

I'd be interested to know if the syntax you're using works for you. Happy metaprogramming!

Comment: The whole idea of ActiveSupport::Concern is to remove (or hide) these `self.included(base)` approaches and make them more readable: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html

Comment: @SebastianvomMeer - Thank you for the link! I guess I'm one of those people who have steered clear of concerns - thus I was not familiar with the syntactic sugar. So, again, thank you for the pointer.